# how to implement spring cloud config server security with docker

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I want to use spring cloud config server security :

I find the example in : https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo/blob/master/application.yml

```
 profile:
    cloud:
            config:
              uri: ${vcap.services.${PREFIX:}configserver.credentials.uri:http://user:password@${PREFIX:}configserver.${application.domain:cfapps.io}}
```

But: i can not  understand : whats the some words  meaning ?

e.g.

1. vcap.services
2. ${PREFIX:}configserver.credentials.uri
3. ${PREFIX:}
4. ${PREFIX:}configserver
5. ${PREFIX:}sso.credentials.tokenUr

And , if i use docker instead of  cloud profile , like this :

```
docker
    config:
      uri: http://${CONFIGSERVER_1_PORT_8888_TCP_ADDR:localhost}:8888

client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${EUREKA_1_PORT_8761_TCP_ADDR:localhost}:8761/eureka/
```

> when i try this :

in coifing-server application.yml :

```
security:
  user:
    password: 1
```

in client-server application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://user:1@localhost:8888
```

The client-server console has errors :

```
 c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
  c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: label not found
```

> Whole Code is in :  https://github.com/keryhu/coud-config-security

How do i implement security config   ?

can help me?

Comment: Your client log is telling you that `CONFIGSERVER_PORT_8888_TCP_ADDR` is not set isn't it? Maybe you have a spelling error (your question is littered with them)?

Comment: sorry, my local workspace is spring cloud with docker , after I met this issue ,To simplify the problem i start another new simple demo without docker config, and put it in the github . now i correct the above description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the config server URI in bootstrap.yml (or .properties) because it is needed in the bootstrap phase.

Comment: I add "spring-cloud-starter-config" dependence in client-server ,,now error is : Could not locate PropertySource: label not found ,   and i follow your Suggests -put "spring.cloud.config.uri " in client-server bootstrap .yml  , but error is the same -" could not locate PropertySource:label not found",,

Comment: That's weird. Maybe you have a mixture of versions. Stick to Brixton or Angel (Brixton snapshots I know this is all working).

Comment: yes,this day,i rewrite the Brixton versions and dependences , it works as expected ! thanks your help !

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure custom spring security configuration?
url and credentials to access config server needs to be setup in bootstrap phase

additional you can change security using WebSecurityConfigurer

    `@Configuration
    @EnableWebMvcSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {`

Comment: Unfortunately ， i use spring boot setting the security ,it not working ,and the whole code is in https://github.com/keryhu/coud-config-security , can some help me ? thanks !

Comment: move config key spring.cloud.config.uri from application.yml to bootstrap.yml